# Is there way to use xbuild instead of build when calling cargo-binutils commands?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, binutils, cross-build

I try to use binutils commands for binary of custom build target with `cargo xbuild` command.
However, I get an error like below message.

```
$ cargo nm --target i586-rust_dos.json --bin rust_dos --verbose
"cargo" "build" "--target" "i586-rust_dos.json" "--bin" "rust_dos" "--message-format=json"
   Compiling rust_dos v0.1.0 (/home/soya/Documents/src/rust/prac/rust_dos)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`                                ] 0/2
  |
  = note: the `i586-rust_dos-8410465322435951119` target may not be installed

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `rust_dos`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
error: Failed to parse crate metadata
```

I realized that `cargo nm` uses `cargo build` command,
so I think this error should be solved if I make `cargo nm` to use `cargo xbuild` instead of `cargo build`.

However, I cannot find how to do that.
Please teach me if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

To detect `core` crate built with `cargo xbuild`, I need to add `sysroot` flag in `rustflags` in `.cargo/config`.

example is below.

```
rustflags = ["--sysroot", "/full/path/to/sysroot/directory"]
```

There is sysroot directory in project's target directory.

If adding these flags, cargo-bintuils commands are enabled to use as far as in my environment.